# formatter in python

Tags: python

I'm going through exercises in a python book and I'm a bit puzzled by what is going on in this code.

```
formatter = "%r %r %r %r"

print formatter % (1, 2, 3, 4)
print formatter % ("one", "two", "three", "four")
print formatter % (True, False, False, True)
print formatter % (formatter, formatter, formatter, formatter)
print formatter % (
    "I had this thing.",
    "That you could type up right.",
    "But it didn't sing.",
    "So I said goodnight."
)
```

The author offer no explanation as to what "formatter" is doing after each "print".  If I remove them, everything prints out exactly the same.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not print out the exact same thing. There are no commas, and no parenthesis if you use the `formatter %` part.

It'll be clearer if you *expand* the formatter. I suggest you use:

```
formatter = "One: %r, Two: %r, Three: %r, Four: %r"
```

instead.

The formatter acts as a template, each `%r` acting as a place holder for the values in the tuple on the right-hand side.

Comment: It is the exact same if I take out ONLY "formatter", leaving % in.
I know without %, it would be totally different.  But I'm curious about specifically "formatter".

Comment: @user1641994: edit your question to show the code that prints the same thing. I can assure you that `print % (1, 2, 3, 4)` is not valid Python syntax.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I screwed up saving it or something before.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`formatter` is a string.  so, the first line is the same as:

```
"%r %r %r %r" % (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

which calls `repr` on each of the items in the tuple on the right and replaces the corresponding `%r` by the result.  Of course, it does the exact same thing for

```
formatter % ("one", "two", "three", "four")
```

and so on as well.

Note that you'll often also see:

```
"%s %s %s %s" % (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

which calls `str` instead of `repr`.  (In your example, I think that `str` and `repr` return the same things for all of those objects, so the output will be exactly the same if you change `formatter` to use `%s` instead of `%r`)

Answer (score 2):

That's the classic format for string formatting, `print "%r" % var` will print the raw value of var, four %r expects 4 variables to be passed after the %.

A better example would be:

```
formatter = "first var is %r, second is %r, third is %r and last is %r"
print formatter % (var1, var2, var3, var4)
```

The use of a formatter variable is just to avoid using a long line in the print but usually there's no need of that.

```
print "my name is %s" % name
print "the item %i is $%.2f" % (itemid, price)
```

`%.2f` is float with 2 values after comma.

There's a newer variant of string formatting you may wish to try: (if you're using at least 2.6)

```
print "my name is {name} I'm a {profession}".format(name="sherlock holmes", profession="detective")
```

More at:

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/

http://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/new-string-formatting-syntax/